# cordova deviceready firing issue

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova

I am using cordova.js in my index.html for my ios app using javascript.First time login my app,deviceready function calls correctly and when i click logout, my app logout successfully and the very next moment i click login, this device ready event never calls

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  `function onDeviceReady(){
       runningInCordova =true;
 }'
```

How to reinitialize the cordova[During logout, i want to remove this device ready .so whenever i click login this device ready event fires].

Actually my issue was,I used openFB for my ios app.It works well for the first time login my application via facebook login.when i logout my app then i tried to login my app via facebook, it did not worked. First time onDeviceReady method calls,so the variable runningInCordova is true when i logout my app that variable runningInCordova is false. How can i fixed that please help me……

Comment: After logout, cordova never initialize so inAppBrowser's loadstart event never calls.How to loadstart event make to work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready):

> #### `deviceready`
>
> The event fires when Cordova is fully loaded.
>
> This event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

The `deviceready` event will only ever fire once - when the application is first loaded. I expect you want to bind different handlers, both for login and logout, instead of using `deviceready`.

Comment: Here, after logot i used window.location.replace("./index.html").But in the index.html page i used this cordova.js.